# Compress in c# and decompress in LINQ To Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this problem: I'm trying to compress a piece of information coming from "outside" and store into a database table (managed by EF 6.x) with a maximum length of 255 chars.

I'm using C#, framework 4.7.2.

So far, pretty easy.
The "problem" is that, once it is in the DB, I need to read it (and decompress/make it readable again) into a LINQ To Entities query.
So, if I don't want to materialize the query (and I can't), I need to be smart about it and compress it in a way I can get it back using the limited functions I have at my disposal in LINQ To Entities

Do you have suggestions? So far, I didn't have any luck looking ad SqlFunctions or DbFunctions classes for this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you compress and decompress in memory instead of trying to to it in SQL?

Comment: @DStanley how do I "decompress" when I'm reading from the db without materializing?

Comment: Why do you need to decompress it before materialization?

Comment: AFAIK that would not be possible, but I would take another look at the "why" around why you believe you need to decompress the value prior to materialization. The only reason I can think of is that you want a compressed string that you could search across within a query. That will not be possible, and even if you stored an entire larger string (I.e. VARCHAR(MAX)) it would be strongly unadvisable.

Comment: @GuruStron The reason is that I want to return a IQueryable, so the "upper" layer will apply filter, pagination and so on. If I materialize it before, I'm going to get all the data, that would kill my performance

Comment: @StevePy I need to fit a big string into a 255, hence the reason why I want to compress it, but in a way that I can decompress and look into it without materializing the query when that value is retrieved

Comment: @ff8mania It seems that you have misunderstood my question. Just do not perform decompression and that's it.

Comment: @GuruStron I see, but how do I look into the content if I don't decompress it?

Comment: TBH if you want to process look into contents then store them as uncompressed. What DB are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron sorry, but If I could store it as uncompressed, I wouldn't have a problem :) I need that string to be compressed into 255 char on the db

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't need to inspect the compressed value within the query itself, such as expecting to filter `Where` clauses and the like using the contents of the compressed string, then you can delegate the compression/decompression to a C# helper method. You do not need to "materialize" the entire entity/graph to be able to get the value, just perform the decompression after you are done retrieving the entity(ies) you want or have done your projection.

For example I create a static helper methods for the compression and decompression:

```
public static string CompressString(string source)
{ ... }

public static string DecompressString(string source)
{ ... }
```

In the database you might have a value called "BigString" so in the entity we can have a BigString property and if the consumer of the entity never needs to see the compressed value, we can mark it as `protected`. Then we can expose a non-mapped decompressed version of the BigString which decompresses our value on demand:

```
public class SomeEntityWithBigString
{
    // ...


    protected string BigString { get; set; }

    private string? _decompressedBigString = null;
    [NotMapped]
    public string DecompressedBigString
    {
        get { return _decompressedBigString ??= Compressor.DecompressString(BigString); }
        set 
        {
            _decompressedBigString = value;
            BigString = Compressor.CompressString(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you want to project the BigString out into a ViewModel or DTO, you can use a similar property approach in the ViewModel to perform the decompression. You would project out the raw BigString value then the ViewModel has an accessor to reveal the decompressed value. You do not need to materialize the entire entity or such to return the compressed data.

The caveat of this approach as I mentioned in the comments is that you cannot query against the decompressed value. So if the string contains keywords or such that you want to filter on, you cannot use it in something like a `Where` clause.  Searching for values within large strings is extremely expensive, so if that is a requirement then you would be well off to introduce a schema update to split off searchable keywords into a one-to-many SomeEntityKeyWords relationship where the large text can be split up into multiple searchable and indexable terms, then manage keeping those in sync if the BigString value ever changes.